# "Recommended question" flag

Tags: feature-request

I'd like to suggest a kind of "Recommended question" flag that could be set by users with enough reputation (possibly using a voting like for closing a question). To make this more exclusive, one could also restrict this award to questions with enough upvotes and an (accepted?) and also upvoted answer.

This could create an fine collection of outstanding questions I'd very much like to browse in the evening after work for my own enlightment :) ...

Comment: A tag doesn't seem right to me, if we're going to do this, make it an actual button.

Comment: also don't think it should be a tag, but it could be a "flag" of some sort. kind of like a green checkmark but for a question, and only vote-able by high-rep users, or maybe for users with lots of experience in the tags that the question is in!

Comment: Sorry. I already had changed the word to "flag" in the text, forgot about the title: I also think, that this should be something different from "ordinary" tags ...

Comment: (-1) for the reasons given in [devinb's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57806/recommended-question-flag/57818#57818).

Answer (score 4):

I think we've already got that with voting.  Wouldn't a question with a high number of votes equate to a community recommended question?  If it's truly notable enough people will upvote it.  Unless, that is, you're looking for more of a daily thing.

Comment: not necessarily, sometimes they're just funny, contentious, or a popular subject, not necessarily a good question or full of good answers

Comment: @eruciform That just means people are using upvotes wrong. Which they are

Comment: @eruc From the FAQ: **"To gain reputation, post good questions and useful answers."**  An upvote on a question indicates that it's a good question to someone.  I guess I just see that as a recommendation.  Enough upvotes from the community shows that it's a really good question.  Maybe someone's voting for it (ie- recommending it) because it's funny, contentious or a popular subject.  I just don't see the difference.

Comment: @eru - the problem would be same with a "recommended question flag", then. You won't prevent people from promoting funny/popular questions.

Comment: @gnoupi: do you think it would be exactly as accurate as current voting, or more, or less?

Answer (score 1):

This suggestion runs very close to the edge of what SO is *for*. Although it does conform quite nicely to the way SO is *used*. :)

StackOverflow is meant as a Q & A site. More than that, it is meant to be a *specific* and *technical* Q & A site. This means that the perfect question (assuming it is well written) would be some sort of bug or obscure framework error. Other options would be a question about how to work around a specific technical limitation.

The major theme of all of them is that the user is approaching a *concrete* problem, with *actionable* solutions. That way if other users are experiencing the same scenario they can enact the same resolution with *hopefully* the same result.

Upvotes are garnered by solutions which (theoretically) *all* solve the problem, with the "best" or most elegant solution bubbling to the top. This means that every StackOverflow problem should be relatively irrelevant to anyone who *doesn't* have that problem.

That is to say, every post should be tailored to it's context. Generalized to help the maximum amount of people *with that problem*.

This makes "Recommended Question" a little out-of-scope. For a question to be applicable enough to be "Everyone should read this!" it has to be far too general to be actionably solvable. How can one question be *specifically* solvable in all OS' and all languages? Well, it would have to be an algorithm question, but each algorithm is designed to solve a particular problem, which means that the "Recommended Question" would only be applicable to people who already have that problem, in which case they would be better served by just searching for it.

---

This means that "Recommended Question" would end up being used for the generalized or subjective questions, which are discouraged anyway.

Lastly, as [squillman](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57806/recommended-question-tag/57808#57808) notes, the "Recommended Questions" could just be considered the questions which are highest voted.